# Motioneye on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero-w, motion

I've installed Motioneye on a Raspberry Pi Zero and connected a camera. I can get it to detect motion, and take an image in response to detected motion. Unfortunately, images are being saved to the target directory as root, rather than user. I'm hoping for suggestions to have motion save them to as user.

I have a Python script that is running periodically as user.  It is intended to upload them to BLOB storage and the delete the files.  Currently, it can upload them, but not delete.  I know I could have that script run as root, but that seems like a generally bad idea.

I've followed the instruction [here](https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneye/wiki/Running-As-Normal-User): Running Motioneye as Normal User, thinking that if Motioneye ran as user, then the image files would be saved using the same permissions.  This provides instructions on how to run Motioneye as a regular user, rather than as root.  However, files are still being saved as root, and when I run htop, it shows the command executed at startup as being owned by user root.  I've attached a screenshot for reference.[image]

If I go in as user and execute: sudo chown -R user:user *, then all of the permissions for the files in the directory are changed to the same owner as the python script I need to execute, and they are deleted as spected.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `I've followed the instruction here` where? Should that have been a link? Your question is also very general. Add more detail, especially about the things you have already tried, etc

Comment: Sorry -- link was missing.  I've corrected this and added additional information.